# what Error in this json file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, json.net, getjson

when i run this json file on Browser i found error and i don't know why ?

and this my full code :

```
 [
 {
     name: "Samsung Tab 3",
     price: 500,
     description:
                    "Samsung Tab 3 is very well "
                 + "Samsung Tab 3 is very well ",
     images: [
          "images/tablet1.png",
          "images/tablet1-thumb.png"
     ],
     reviews: [
     {
         stars: 5,
         body: "I Love this Tab",
         author: "Michael.Gamel@hotmail.com"
     },
     {
         stars: 1,
         body: "this tab sucks",
         author: "samir@hotmail.com"
     }
     ],
     processor: " Core™2 Duo",
     ram: "1 GB",
     colors: ["White","Red","Blue"],
     canPurchase: true,
     soldOut: false
 }
 ,
 {
     name: "Apple iPad 4",
     price: 500.50,
     description:
                    "Apple iPad 4 is very well "
                 + "Apple iPad 4 is very well ",
     images: [
          "images/tablet2.png",
          "images/tablet2-thumb.png"
     ],
     reviews: [
     {
         stars: 3,
         body: "I Love this Tab",
         author: "Michael.Gamel@hotmail.com"
     },
     {
         stars: 4,
         body: "this tab sucks",
         author: "samir@hotmail.com"
     }
     ],
     processor: "core i3",
     ram: "2 GB",
     colors: ["Black", "Yellow", "Brown"],
     canPurchase: true,
     soldOut: false
 }
    ]
```

i found error in name and my browser tell me :

Error: Parse error on line 2:
 [     {         name: "Samsung Tab 3
-----------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'

what this mean ??!!

Comment: This is something you can debug on your own: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the **key** names...

```
"name": "Samsung Tab 3",
```

The main issue here is the formatting in the *description*. You will get issues with syntax like:

```
"Samsung Tab 3 is very well "
                 + "Samsung Tab 3 is very well ",
```

Take a look at [*JSONLint*](http://jsonlint.com/) too, this will help validate your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the property names for it to be valid json: http://json.org/example

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the JavaScript string concatenation
Like this:

```
description : "Samsung Tab 3 is very well " 
+ "Samsung Tab 3 is very well "
```

Try this:

```
[{
    name : "Samsung Tab 3",
    price : 500,
    description : "Samsung Tab 3 is very well " + "Samsung Tab 3 is very well ",
    images : [
        "images/tablet1.png",
        "images/tablet1-thumb.png"
    ],
    reviews : [{
            stars : 5,
            body : "I Love this Tab",
            author : "Michael.Gamel@hotmail.com"
        }, {
            stars : 1,
            body : "this tab sucks",
            author : "samir@hotmail.com"
        }
    ],
    processor : " Core™2 Duo",
    ram : "1 GB",
    colors : ["White", "Red", "Blue"],
    canPurchase : true,
    soldOut : false
}, {
    name : "Apple iPad 4",
    price : 500.50,
    description : "Apple iPad 4 is very well " + "Apple iPad 4 is very well ",
    images : [
        "images/tablet2.png",
        "images/tablet2-thumb.png"
    ],
    reviews : [{
            stars : 3,
            body : "I Love this Tab",
            author : "Michael.Gamel@hotmail.com"
        }, {
            stars : 4,
            body : "this tab sucks",
            author : "samir@hotmail.com"
        }
    ],
    processor : "core i3",
    ram : "2 GB",
    colors : ["Black", "Yellow", "Brown"],
    canPurchase : true,
    soldOut : false
}]
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RRTTW/)**